# missing "is" in the sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

The text is:

> The free of them sat in silence for a moment, the only sound the crackling of the fire.

I can guess, the text should be "The free of them sat in silence for a moment, the only sound **is** the crackling of the fire."

Can you explain to me why "IS" is missed and what missing "IS" is meaning for English people.

Answer (score 2):

Just to deal with it at the start, your sentence probably starts with an error, substituting "The free of them" for "The three of them".

The sentence could be restated using a form of "to be", but not the form "is":

> "The three of them sat in silence for a moment, the only sound **being** the crackling of the fire.

The part after the comma is a parenthetical clause, that is, the sentence is still grammatical if it is removed completely.
When the verb "being" is removed, it becomes an appositive clause, that is, it equates two things ("the only noise" and "the crackling of the fire") by placing them next to each other (apposing them), without using the copulative verb "being". The meaning is exactly the same without "being".

The clause "the only sound the crackling of the fire" is found in twelve different places at Google books, so it's almost a cliché. There are also several instances of the clause including the verb "being".

There are also instances of a similar structure with "the only light [being] the...", "the only traffic [being], and similar examples, which can be found with and without "being".

Comment: With the past tense _sat_, it would have to be _was_ anyway!

Comment: It's called an [absolute clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).